# How do I use the curved edge style in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

A recent release of mxGraph has added curves as a style for edges. I expected this to be an edge routing style, but it seems not. Could anyone show me a small example of a graph with curved edges?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually the shape style of the edge:

```
style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();
style[mxConstants.STYLE_CURVED] = '1';
```

Sets it for as the default for all edges.

Edge styles are really the positioning of the control points of the edge between the source and target. The curve isn't routing (this points positioning), it's just a styling through those points, thus it's not an edge style.

Answer (score 3):

In the current version you can use something like:

```
    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Map<String, Object> style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();
    style.put(mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED, true);
    style.put(mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE, mxConstants.EDGESTYLE_ENTITY_RELATION);
```

Comment: The question relates to JavaScript, not Java.