# How to force jGraphX to use straight lines

Tags: java, mxgraph, jgraphx

I am creating a huge diagram with jGraphX, but for easier preview it would be easier to follow if the diagram was using straight lines instead of lines that have corners

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you checked this question and its answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378514/how-do-i-use-the-curved-edge-style-in-mxgraph

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that question only asks for the lines to have curves instead of hard corners, I basically wan't no corners, just straight direct lines